# How to combine count and for loop in a python function?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, count, range

I am trying to write a function that finds a percentage in a list. Easy enough, right? my only problem is the category I'm trying to find a percentage of in my data has several integers associated with it, so for example the scores 9,10, and 11 all are in one category. Here is my percent finding function with a little example:

```py
def percent_score(Scores,Level):
    
    find = Scores.count(Level)
    perc = find/len(Scores)
    return perc


Prac_1 = [9,10,5,14,7,18,10,10,10,9,11]
Lvl = 10

percent_score(Prac_1,Lvl)
```

How can I add in a for loop like this to find the percentage of occurrances of 9,10, and 11 in my list? (this was my attempt but it didn't work):

```py
x = range (9,12)

for x in Lvl:
    print(percent_score(Prac_1,Lvl))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop is almost correct, instead of putting `Lvl` as a function parameter, put `x` there instead:

```py
def percent_score(Scores, Level):
    find = Scores.count(Level)
    perc = find / len(Scores)
    return perc


Prac_1 = [9, 10, 5, 14, 7, 18, 10, 10, 10, 9, 11]

for x in range(9, 12):
    print(percent_score(Prac_1, x))
```

Prints:

```
0.18181818181818182
0.36363636363636365
0.09090909090909091
```

---

With prettier string formatting:

```py
for l in range(9, 12):
    print(f"{l} : {percent_score(Prac_1, l):.2f}%")
```

Prints:

```
9 : 0.18%
10 : 0.36%
11 : 0.09%
```

Comment: Ah! It's always the little things... Is there a way to count all of those in one percentage together? Taking the average of averages isn't accurate at all so I'm trying to avoid that.  For example, instances of 9, 10, and 11 are 65% of the entire set.